# Strange behavior when using union in Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am trying to use a union statement to combine 2 tables in Access.  I don't quite understand why, but I'm having trouble getting the result I want. It would be great if someone could help me here. I use the following initial situation

tblBewohner
[image]

tblPersonal
[image]

If I use the following union statement:

```
 SELECT tblBewohner.calcBewohnerName, tblBewohner.idBewohner
FROM (tblVeranstaltung INNER JOIN (tblBewohner INNER JOIN tblBewohnerVeranstaltung ON tblBewohner.idBewohner = tblBewohnerVeranstaltung.frkBewohner) ON tblVeranstaltung.idVeranstaltung = tblBewohnerVeranstaltung.frkVeranstaltung) INNER JOIN (tblTagesplan INNER JOIN tblVeranstaltungTagesplan ON tblTagesplan.idTagesplan = tblVeranstaltungTagesplan.frkTagesplan) ON tblVeranstaltung.idVeranstaltung = tblVeranstaltungTagesplan.frkVeranstaltung
union

SELECT tblPersonal.calcPersonalName, tblPersonal.idPersonal
FROM (tblVeranstaltung INNER JOIN (tblPersonal INNER JOIN tblPersonalVeranstaltung ON tblPersonal.idPersonal = tblPersonalVeranstaltung.frkPersonal) ON tblVeranstaltung.idVeranstaltung = tblPersonalVeranstaltung.frkVeranstaltung) INNER JOIN (tblTagesplan INNER JOIN tblVeranstaltungTagesplan ON tblTagesplan.idTagesplan = tblVeranstaltungTagesplan.frkTagesplan) ON tblVeranstaltung.idVeranstaltung = tblVeranstaltungTagesplan.frkVeranstaltung;
```

I get the following result:

[image]

So you can see, that there are missing column and the data is some kind of mixed up. Could you please give me an advice, what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank you in advance

Comment: For one, use table aliases when referencing the same table more than once in a `SELECT` statement. Give tblVeranstaltung one alias for the first JOIN it's in and new aliases each time you use the table in a different `JOIN`. Aliases are created using the`AS` keyword. e.g., `SELECT * FROM tblVeranstaltung AS V1`, then use V2 or whatever makes sense to you. Precede field names using the alias as you would with a table name, e.g., `V1.[My_Field]`. Aliases help rdbms avoid confusion.

Comment: I don't see missing columns nor mixed up data. The output is exactly what the UNION prescribes. What you should do is use alias field names in the first SELECT as it is the first SELECT that dictates field names used as well as their data types. Can also have a calculated field. `SELECT tblBewohner.calcBewohnerName AS DataName, tblBewohner.idBewohner AS DataID, "tblB" AS Source ` Edit question to show desired output. Data should be posted as text tables, not images.

Comment: Yes, @June7 is right, nothing wrong here. No fields are missing, as you use the calculated field. If you wish a specific order, append that to the last query.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you for your efforts and help. Perhaps I somehow misunderstood the Union issue then. I think have to read more deeply into unions. Thank you again

Comment: Why do you have two tables with same kind of data?

Comment: @June7: You're right, of course, that's not the right approach. I am only just getting to grips with access and will adapt this. Thank you so much.